# prefersStatusBarHidden iOS 13 not called

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, statusbar

I've always used

`override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {return true}`

to hide the status bar in a single `UIViewController` .. But I'm having problems with **iOS 13** for this ...

I don't understand why `var prefersStatusBarHidden`
is not called ..

in my plist file I set `View controller-based status bar appearance = YES` but it doesn't work ...

the status bar is always visible ... how can I solve it?

Comment: Describe the view controller hierarchy. Only the top level view controller (such as the root of the whole app) gets this call. Where is your view controller?

Comment: @matt ... is a first view controller of my app with navigation bar .. i initialise this view controller from scene delegate

Comment: Ok, so is your simulator / device like an iPhone X? You cannot hide the status bar if the navigation controller is showing its navigation bar.

Comment: @matt I am working on my real device (iPhoneX MAX) and in this ViewController the navigation bar is hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On an iPhone X-type device (anything without a bezel), Apple does not want you to hide the status bar, so your view controller's `prefersStatusBarHidden` is not called.

You may be able to work around this by subclassing UINavigationViewController; in my testing, that worked, but I don't know whether Apple would approve.

Comment: Ok then I'll try to manage the color of the status bar also this creates problems at times ... it doesn't change color ... however now I try again changing only the color ..

Thanks a lot matt

Comment: There is no provision whatever for changing the status bar color. It has no color. It is transparent and you cannot change that.

Comment: I mean the text color status bar light or dark :)

Comment: thank you again for your availability, I posted another question always on apple guidelines regarding the SignIn With Apple button .. can you have a look when you have time? :)

Comment: I forgot to send you the link I'm sorry https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60919194/custom-circular-button-for-signin-with-apple

Comment: Man WHERE is this documented? I spent more time than should have been necessary only to find this out. Thanks for making this known.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide status bar throughout application so in your project

Go to General->Deployment Info->Status bar style and select check mark of Hide status bar.