# Custom circular button for SignIn with Apple

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, mask, sign-in-with-apple

I'm following Apple's guidelines for implementing the "Sign in with Apple" button. In the documentation apple says that it is also possible to use only the logo to create a custom button of "Log in with Apple), also you can also change the shape of the image to have a circular button ...

In order to be able to edit the image it also provides insert a mask but I don't understand that we have to create a mask for the button or the selected image.

This is what apple wrote in the documentation

[image]

At this point how can I get the sign in button with apple with only the circular logo?

Comment: Have you found a solution or better say a clarification for that? I have same problem. I don't understand if i have to apply corner radius to the button or mask the image inside the button. Another problem is that the image has its own padding, so even if the image's size fills the button, if you apply corner radius to the button its background color should be the same as logo's image (black or white), if clear you will not see the rounded corner. If you apply the mask to the image you need to consider padding size too.

Comment: @MrHim I've added the solution which worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use PNG, PDF Apple icons provided by **Apple inc** from a DMG file (Released by Apple).
Here is the link https://devimages-cdn.apple.com/design/resources/download/Logo-SIWA.dmg

Answer (score 0):

You can download de svg icon in that link:

https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround! also got my app approved by the Apple review team.

What I did is,

1. Take `UIImageView` with the same size of other social media logos in your app.

   ```
   @IBOutlet var imgAppleLogo: UIImageView!
   ```
2. set the `SVG` icon(from apple design [resources](https://developer.apple.com/design/resources/)).
3. Set background color and corner radius as below:

   ```
   imgAppleLogo.layer.cornerRadius = imgAppleLogo.frame.size.height / 2
   imgAppleLogo.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
   ```

Done!

I had to set the background color to fill up the default padding of the apple icon. Otherwise the icon won't be circular.

You can follow the same even if you take `UIButton`.

By doing this, we are not modifying the default apple icon and so not breaking the Apple guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

#### SwiftUI solution

I needed a Circular sign-in button. I first downloaded a circular image at [this link](https://appleid.apple.com/signinwithapple/button). I used these settings as I needed a 50pt image.
[See this image for my settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehSF1.png)

Then I imported my image into Assets and used it in my view:

```
struct AppleSignInBtn: View {
var action: () -> Void
var body: some View {
    Button {
        action()
    } label: {
        Image("apple_logo")
            .foregroundColor(.white)
    }
    .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
}
```

Now I can use it in any view like this:

```
AppleSignInBtn {
    print("Apple Sign In pressed")
}
```